# Spring Boot query não retorna registros

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jdbc, java-8

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema com Java 8 e Spring Boot com JDBC acessando uma base Oracle. Quando faço uma query, utilizando o NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, o mesmo não retorna nenhum registro, porém se eu copio essa mesma query e faço uma busca direto no client do Oracle, os registros retornam normalmente. Segue o método que faz a busca:

```
    public Optional<Objeto> busca(String campo4, String campo3, String campo2) {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("SELECT CAMPO_1,                          ");
        sql.append("  CAMPO_2,                               ");
        sql.append("  CAMPO_3,                               ");
        sql.append("  CAMPO_4,                               ");
        sql.append("  CAMPO_5,                               ");
        sql.append("  CAMPO_6                                ");
        sql.append("FROM TABELA_DO_BANCO                     ");
        sql.append("                WHERE CAMPO_4 = :pCampo4 ");
        sql.append("                AND CAMPO_2 = :pCampo2   ");
        sql.append("                AND CAMPO_3 = :pCampo3   ");

        return this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sql.toString(), new MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue("pCampo4", campo4, Types.INTEGER)
            .addValue("pCampo2", campo2)
            .addValue("pCampo3", campo3)
                            , new ObjetoRowMapper())
                .stream().findFirst();
}
```

Segue a descrição do banco de dados:

[image: Descrição da tabela]

Acredito que o problema está no **WHERE** com o campo *CAMPO_2*, pois quando retiro ele da query, o sistema retorna os registros esperados. Alguém tem alguma ideia do que seja? Alguém já passou por isso?

Abraços.

Comment: Onde está o `CAMPO_8`?

Comment: Na verdade é o CAMPO_2, já corrigi o post. Obrigado.

Comment: Inspeciona o valor que está na variável campo2. Além disso, coloca a consulta que você rodou por fora, pois se o problema é na consulta do Java, provavelmente é relativo ao valor dos campos que você injetou na query.

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra inspecionei e o valor está normal.

Comment: Inclua a consulta que você está realizando por fora da aplicação, conforme foi solicitado pela @GiulianaBezerra.

Comment: Segue o sql retirado direto do código:
SELECT CAMPO_1, CAMPO_2, CAMPO_3, CAMPO_4, CAMPO_5, CAMPO_6 FROM SDE_PARAM_VALID_CRM WHERE CAMPO_4 = 112 AND CAMPO_2 = 337941320001 AND CAMPO_3 = 'AC';

Comment: Você tem certeza que essa *query* está executando? Perceba que a coluna `CAMPO_2` é do tipo `VARCHAR2` e você está comparando ela com um valor numérico.

Comment: Então, coloquei o *Types.VARCHAR* no addValue do **CAMPO_2**, mas não resolveu.

Comment: Acredito que `campo2`, `campo3` e `campo4` devem todos ser tratados como `Types.VARCHAR2` ou `Types.CHAR` conforme o caso.

Comment: @Piovezan não consegui encontrar o `Types.VARCHAR2` e tratei como `Types.CHAR` mas não funcionou.

Comment: @WellingtonGonçalves Foram só sugestões, não conheço o framework.

Comment: @Piovezan aah sim, muito obrigado kkkk, mas tentei colocar todos os `Types` mas nenhum funcionou :(